# SSRS - Unzip image varbinary(max) data and display

Tags: image, reporting-services

I'm working with a database-driven application that allows users to upload images which are then zipped and embedded into a database in a varbinary(max) format. I am now trying to get that image to display within an SSRS report (using BI 2005).

How can I convert the file data (which is 65,438 characters long when zipped and 65,535 characters when not zipped) into a normal varbinary format that I can then display in SSRS?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to embed a reference to a dll in your project and use a function to decompress the data within SSRS, see for example [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/). Consider storing the data uncompressed if possible, as the CPU / space trade off is unlikely to be in your favour here, as impage data is likely to have a poor compression ratio (it is usually already compressed).